# data:image backgrounds break for stylesheets linked to from inside the polymer-element template

Tags: polymer

See the `<swiper-slider>` element I'm trying to create here:

https://github.com/leoj3n/swiper-slider

Specifically this file:

https://github.com/leoj3n/swiper-slider/blob/master/swiper-slider.html#L19

Install it and inspect `<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>` to see how the `background-image` CSS links to `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg...` that, when opened in new tab, reports: `error on line 1 at column 11: AttValue: " or ' expected`.

If I add the following declaration:

```
.swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-185-114-8.jpg');
}
```

To the `<style>` tag after the include, a background image appears so I'm not sure why it's having issues with the `data:image/svg+xml`.

Any insights as to why `data:image/svg+xml` for CSS background is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding and re-encoding your data URL, I ended up with this:

`url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20viewBox%3D%270%200%2027%2044%27%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%27M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z%27%20fill%3D%27%23007aff%27%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");`

With the URL-escaped single quotes, this appears to work fine for me in shadow DOM:

http://jsbin.com/qorawe/1/edit?html,css,console,output

I'm not sure why this is working differently inside and outside of a custom element, though.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's the workaround I needed to finish my custom element. Re-declaring images in `<style>` sucks because future Swiper updates might break this hack but works for now so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the encoding "charset=utf-8" and it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It's not an issue with the charset parameter but an issue with how Polymer is handling quotes when inlining CSS from `<style>`. I've raised an issue on the Polymer GitHub: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1276

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from [this Github issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1276):

One workaround is to replace any quotes inside the url function with url encoded characters:

Double quotes (") replaced with '%22':

```
my-css-selector {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 16 16%22><path d=%22M5.7 2L4.3 3.4 8.88 8l-4.6 4.6L5.7 14l6-6z%22/></svg>');
}
```

Tested to work with Polymer 1.4.0, Chrome (Desktop), Safari (Desktop and Mobile), Firefox and Edge. IE11 fails to render the SVG.